# combine shinyFiles::shinyDirButton and shiny::verbatimTextOutput to mimic look of shiny::fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a module that uses the server logic of `shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose()` but mimics the look and feel of `shiny::fileInput()`. It seems like this is essentially just a combo of `shinyFiles::shinyDirButton()` and `shiny::verbatimTextOutput()`. The server and ui are working but I am struggling to style the ui in a way to match `shiny::fileInput()`. I've tried a variety of things looking at the source code of `shiny::fileInput()` but I haven't figured out. I would appreciate help with

1. Setting the display so that `shinyDirButton()` and `verbatimTextOutput()` are side-by-side.
2. Setting the fonts to match `fileInput()`.
3. Fixing the click box of `shinyDirButton()`, since right now the button click window seems to include the label.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(htmltools)

outputdirselector_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    ns = session$ns

    volumes = c(tempdir = tempdir(), home = "~")

    shinyDirChoose(input, "selectDir", session = session,
      roots = volumes, defaultRoot = names(volumes)[1],
      allowDirCreate = TRUE, updateFreq = 0)

    output$displayDir = renderText({
      if (is.integer(input$selectDir)) {
        "Select a directory..."
      } else {
        parseDirPath(volumes, input$selectDir)
      }
    })
  })
}


outputdirselector_ui = function(id, width = "100%") {
  ns = NS(id)

    div(class = "form-group shiny-input-container", style = css(width = validateCssUnit(width)),
      HTML(sprintf("<label class=\"control-label\" id=\"%s-label\" for=\"%s\">Output Directory</label>",
        ns("selectDir"), ns("selectDir"))),
      div(class = "input-group",
        span(shinyDirButton(ns("selectDir"), "Output Directory", "Select output directory...", viewtype = "list")),
        span(verbatimTextOutput(ns("displayDir"), placeholder = TRUE))
      )
    )
}

# run it
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(outputdirselector_ui("foo")),
  function(input,output,session) outputdirselector_server("foo")
)
```